AWS amplify Predictions Text-to-Speech Error in react native cli
i want to use aws amplify Predictions text to speech in react native cli  when i add and call it in a function it show this error {"err": [Error: Cannot create URL for blob!]} how to solve this error

const generateSpeech = async () => {
const speechResult = await Predictions.convert({
textToSpeech: {
source: {
text: 'Hello',
>         },
voiceId: 'Kimberly',
languageCode: 'en-US',
>       },
>     });

